# Strange Behaviour Tapping Web Links on Android

Tags: android, css

I'm having an issue with a standard navigation bar in my HTC Desire Android default browser. When I try to tap one of the hyperlinks it's not very responsive, it takes around 3 or 4 taps to actually navigate to another page.

An interesting observation is that if I remain tapped on a link while pressing down for a second, the webkit's green border can be seen just above the actual link itself. My first port of call was checking my CSS, but there are no rules to indicate any padding on the links.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about/">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I had problems with was HttpUrlConnection caching the old connection, trying to keep the same socket alive I guess? I don't know a lot about it. Anyways, I added the line:

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");//This line placed before the connection
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

And it seemed to get rid of the problem of Android attempting to reuse an old connection that wasn't valid anymore.  One of the things I noticed in my app was that before a certain amount of time, or every other time I tried to use this HttpUrlConnection from a utility class, the app would be non-responsive or crash. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the kind of functionality I'm looking at. This seems to be a rendering issue with webkit. I appear to have fixed it.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have come from the following CSS rule:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

Removing this rule in my CSS restored the tap accuracy on the Android device.